# Parameter Validation using Java Annotation

Tags: java

I understand, in Java we have parameters validation solution. I believe JAX-RS has various annotations both for validation and data extraction. My question is, if I want to implement my own parameter validation class for a standalone Java application, how would I make sure that a method is executed only when its parameters have been validated? I am using Reflection to spot parameters with `@LowerCaseCheck` and then performing validation on it, but not sure where to place this validation code.

```
public void print(@LowerCaseCheck String lowerCaseString) {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the byte code of the method to perform the check (or call a method which performs the check)  The simplest way to do this might be to use an Aspect orientated library like AspectJ.

Comment: @Abidi Unless you change the byte code, it is just a compiler time check or a comment at best.  If you want to run something, you need byte code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [gag](https://code.google.com/p/gag/) for an example of a library that does what you're looking for. It uses the asm bytecode manipulation library to insert validation checks at the start of annotated methods.

Answer (score 0):

Cant'you use Bean Validation (JSR-303) to solve your problem ? 
the @Pattern(regexp) annotation seems to do just what you need.

```
public void print(@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-z]*$") String lowerCaseString) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: That's right but how does JSR-303 does it? Can this be coded without dealing with bytecode?